# TRIGGER MYSQL TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I started a project for my university, I am new to mysql so this could be a stupid question but here the problem:
I was asked to create a trigger, the idea is that i have one table with all my movies(movieID,movie.title) and i have create another table where I want that every time someone put a new movieID in movies, in my new table it will stamp the new movieID just uploaded and it's current timestamp. I have done that, but when I add a new movie, nothing happens in the other table.

here the new table for the trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE updatemovieid(
 movieID int,
 new_movieID INT,
 update_movieID TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(update_movieID));
```

here the trigger:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER aggiornamento AFTER UPDATE ON movies
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO updatemovieid
VALUES (new.movieID, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
END//
```

The first table name is: movies
the database: netflix

Comment: What is the name of the table netflix.Movies or Movies?

Comment: name of the table:Movies
name of database: netflix

Comment: Then change netflix.Movies to Movies.

Comment: i changed it like this:


DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER aggiornamento AFTER UPDATE ON movies
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO updatemovieid
    VALUES (new.movieID, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
    END//



this is my 1st table: SELECT * FROM netflix.movies;

but still, doesn't work, i mean it is implemented successfully but when I do add a new row in the first table, nothing happens in the updatedmovieid one

Comment: From your question I assume you want to insert a row when someone inserts a row in the other table, try using 'AFTER INSERT'.